# Can URL's in Mysql table be hyperlinks?

Tags: java, mysql, jsoup

I am using Java and Mysql to write a program that scans urls and stores the urls found into a database.
Is it possible to make it so that when I `SELECT * FROM table;` the URL's that are displayed are clickable hyperlinks? 
Thanks

Comment: nope..that is not allowed in mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That makes no sense, hyperlink is a functionality of the client application rather than database. If you want your links to be clickable, that will need to be implemented by the application and MySQL has nothing to do with that.